# Titanium Studio appcelerator (write once run for all)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I am new on Titanium Studio Appcelerator,i have the following questions about titanium studio appcelerator:

1. In titanium if i want to consume Ksoap2 webservices then i will be write code at once?and will be run that code on all plateform?like android/ios.
2. Or the webservices consuming code will be specific to plateform dependent? i mean if i want to consume webservices in titanium then i will write code in all platform(android/ios).

Please some Titanium studio appcelerator experts guid me in right direction Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ksoap2` to do your WebService and use `Ti.Network.createHttpClient` to retrieve the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

All logic and most of the UI can be shared amongst all platforms. A great advantage of Appcelerator Titanium.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through the titanium docs for web services APIs ?

As titanium is a hybrid technology, most of the APIs are common for both the platform, but depends on your need and the API you are using, you may have to write the platform specific code in condition and this code will not affect the others platforms.

From my experience, in the case of web service calling single code will run on both the platform. There are some platform specific properties if need to use them use in a platform specific condition. its a just a few line of code and your code will run in both the platforms